# python random function not working , I am very new at python

Tags: python-extensions

I have used a random function in python but its not working , I am very new at python. Please review below code

```
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['number'] = random.randrange(1, 100)
        return context
```

its rertuning error NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You did not import random module. Add this to the top of your script:

```
import random
```

Comment: Thanks its wrok fine. really appreciate.